# MySQL query. Can't Insert data

Tags: mysql

I was trying to insert data to my table. But it is showing the else part. I couldn't insert data. Please help. my names for values were 'name', 'mail', and 'pass'. as in the second query.

```
    <?php
    if(array_key_exists('name', $_POST) AND array_key_exists('mail', $_POST) 
AND array_key_exists('pass', $_POST)) {
        if($_POST['name'] == "") echo "<p>Name is required</p>";
        if($_POST['mail'] == "") echo "<p>Mail is required</p>";
        if($_POST['pass'] == "") echo "<p>Password is required</p>";

        if($_POST['name'] != "" AND $_POST['mail'] != "" AND $_POST['pass'] 
!= ""){

            $link=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "mydata");
            if(mysqli_connect_error()) echo "Couldn't connect to server, 
Please try again later.";
            else {

                $query = "SELECT `id` FROM TABLE1 WHERE `mail` = 
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['mail'])."'";
                if($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
                  $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                    if($row != "") echo "Email already taken";
                    else {
                        $query = "INSERT INTO `table1` 
('name','mail','password') VALUE ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_POST['name'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, 
$_POST['mail'])."','".mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['pass'])."')";
                        if(mysqli_query($link, $query)) echo "yes";
                        else echo "nooo";
                    }
                }        
            }
        }
    };
?>
```

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: @want2learn for the if statement, It should show "Yes", but instead, it is showing "noo" as in the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

Why not add mysqli_error() into the code.. to see why it failed to insert.

Comment: Thanks Henry, It showed syntac error. The `VALUE` should be replaced with `VALUES`. It worked.